# MySQL running totals in procedure

Tags: mysql, counter, procedure, cumulative-sum

I just cant get this to work within a procedure (as a simple query this works fine):

```
SET @c:=0;
SELECT
    (@c := @c + 1) AS Cumulative,
FROM
    NumberTable,
    Table
...
```

I think it hast something to to with the "counter"-variable. For the procedure I tried:

```
DECLARE c int(4) DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        (c = c + 1) AS Cumulative,
    FROM
        NumberTable,
        Table
    ...
END
```

But that doesn't work (gives NULL). Any suggestions?

PS: I think the question breaks down to this: How to SET a variable within SELECT while using a PROCEDURE (since := does not work there)

Comment: How about using `c= (SELECT count(id) FROM nt,t WHERE ..)`

Comment: You are right, this works for the simple counter. But i also to cumulate some data within the procedure (a = a + b.table). Any additional hint?

Comment: I think the question is, how to SET a variable within SELECT while using a PROCEDURE.

Comment: I am really going desperate on this one. Please help. I need a possibility to set a variable in a select statement within a procedure... Pleeeaaaaase.